# Error to parse from alomofire post request

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire

I have an issue with parsing using alamofire. I get an error to try to decode the json file that i get in return from the request.
I have tried to parse JSON file that looks like this:

```
success({
data =     {
    id = "eb259a9e-1b71-4df3-9d2a-6aa797a147f6";
    nickname = joeDoe;
    options =         {
        avatar = avatar1;
    };
    rooms = "<null>";
};
```

})

It Gives me an error that looks like this:

```
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"id\", intValue: nil) (\"id\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

The user model looks like this:

```
import Foundation

struct userModel: Codable {
    let id: String
    let nickname: String
    let options: options
    let rooms: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "id"
    case nickname = "nickname"
    case options = "options"
    case rooms = "rooms"
    }
}

struct options: Codable {
   var avatar: String?
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case avatar = "avatar"
    }
 }
```

And the function looks like this:

```
    func postUser(){
    AF.request("http://test.com/", method: .post, parameters: user).responseJSON {response  in
        guard let itemsData = response.data else {
            print("test1")
                      return
                    }
                    do {
                        print("hallo!")
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        print("")
                        print(itemsData)
                        print("")
                        print(response.description)
                        let items = try decoder.decode(userModel.self, from: itemsData)
                        print(items)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            print("test2")
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    print("test3")
                    }
}
```

How do i fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring the root object, the dictionary with key `data`.

Create another struct

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let data : UserModel
}
```

And please name structs with starting capital letter and you don't need the CodingKeys if the struct member names match the keys

```
struct UserModel: Codable {
    let id: String
    let nickname: String
    let options: Options
    let rooms: String


struct Options: Codable {
    var avatar: String?
 }
```

Then decode

```
 let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: itemsData)
 let items = result.data
```

Consider that AF can decode JSON with `JSONDecoder` implicitly.

Comment: Yes, please use `responseDecodable`. `responseJSON` already parses your response using `JSONSerialization`, so you're doing a lot of duplicate work. On the main queue as well.

Comment: @JonShier AF dispatches the result to the main thread automatically.

Comment: Well aware. My point was that doing the decoding work in the handler's closure is doing that work on the main queue. Using one of the built in serializers ensures that the work is done in the background.